# Keeping pairs of data that have the same date and time in R

Tags: r, date, join, dplyr, time

I have 2 sets of data that look like this (this is a very small subset of it).

```
data1 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = 
c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000- 
01-02", "2000-01-03",                                                                                        
"2000-01-03", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-07"), "Time" = c("11:00:00", "12:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "13:00:00", "17:00:00", "20:00:00", "20:00:00"), "Value" = c(100, 200, 
300, 100, 400, 500, 500))

data2 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = 
c("P", "P", 
                                                                      "P", "P", "P", 
"P", "P"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000- 
01-03", 
                                                                                                 
"2000-01-04", "2000-01-07"), "Time" = c("11:00:00", "11:00:00", "14:00:00", 
"17:00:00", "13:00:00", "16:00:00", "20:00:00"), "Value" = c(100, 100, 200, 900, 100, 
400, 999))
```

I want to keep data from both tables that have the same date and time and create a new table (data3). Sometimes within data1 and data2, there will be duplicates, I don't want data3 to contain those duplicates, just 1 of them and with its pair from the other table. I would also like the output table to be ordered to show the pairs from each table under each other (so my "Type" column would be alternating F, P, F, P, etc.).

Here is my desired output

```
data3 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", 
"Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = c("F", "P", "F", 
                                                                
"P", "F", "P", "F", "P"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", 
"2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2001-01- 
07", "2001-01-07"), "Time" = 
                  c("11:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"13:00:00", "17:00:00", "17:00:00", "20:00:00", "20:00:00"), 
"Value" = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 400, 900, 500, 999))
```

I have tried using various types of joins from dplyr, but they aren't joining the way I'd like it to.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: An example would be in data1 where the Metal, Type, Date, Time, and Value are all the same in the final 2 rows. So all of the columns please!

Comment: Suppose you have more than one pair for the same Metal, Type, Date, Time, do you only select the first pair.  I assume that condition in creating the solution below

Answer (score 1):

We may need bind the data, and then `filter` out the duplicates after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(data1, data2, .id = 'grp')%>%
  group_by(Metal, Date, Time) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  arrange(Date, Time, rowid(grp)) %>%
  slice(match(c("F", "P"), Type)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Metal Type  Date       Time     Value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1 Al    F     2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
2 Al    P     2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
3 Al    F     2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
4 Al    P     2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
5 Al    F     2000-01-03 17:00:00   400
6 Al    P     2000-01-03 17:00:00   900
7 Al    F     2000-01-07 20:00:00   500
8 Al    P     2000-01-07 20:00:00   999
```

-OP's data

```
> data3
  Metal Type       Date     Time Value
1    Al    F 2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
2    Al    P 2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
3    Al    F 2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
4    Al    P 2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
5    Al    F 2000-01-03 17:00:00   400
6    Al    P 2000-01-03 17:00:00   900
7    Al    F 2001-01-07 20:00:00   500
8    Al    P 2001-01-07 20:00:00   999
```

Comment: I swear I did the first rows without seeing your solution. It makes me happy to see that I had the same line of thought.

Answer (score 1):

This was not easy :-)

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data1, data2) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Time) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  arrange(Time) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(Type == "P" & lag(Type, default = last(Type)) == "F", 1, NA)) %>% 
  mutate(Flag1 = lead(Flag)) %>% 
  filter(if_any(.cols = starts_with("Flag"), .fns = ~ . == 1)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("Flag"))
```

```
  Metal Type  Date       Time     Value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1 Al    F     2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
2 Al    P     2000-01-01 11:00:00   100
3 Al    F     2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
4 Al    P     2000-01-03 13:00:00   100
5 Al    F     2000-01-03 17:00:00   400
6 Al    P     2000-01-03 17:00:00   900
7 Al    F     2000-01-07 20:00:00   500
8 Al    P     2000-01-07 20:00:00   999
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach with `inner_join`

The difficulty here is getting the right format, the mere data filter itself is done after the inner_join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

joined <- inner_join(data1 %>% distinct(), data2 %>% distinct(), 
            c("Metal", "Date", "Time"))

joined
  Metal Type.x       Date     Time Value.x Type.y Value.y
1    Al      F 2000-01-01 11:00:00     100      P     100
2    Al      F 2000-01-03 13:00:00     100      P     100
3    Al      F 2000-01-03 17:00:00     400      P     900
4    Al      F 2000-01-07 20:00:00     500      P     999
```

Arranging data

```
joined %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Type"), values_to="Type") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Value = c_across(starts_with("Value"))[c(F=1, P=2)[Type]]) %>% 
  select(-contains("."), -name) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Metal Date       Time     Type  Value
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 Al    2000-01-01 11:00:00 F       100
2 Al    2000-01-01 11:00:00 P       100
3 Al    2000-01-03 13:00:00 F       100
4 Al    2000-01-03 13:00:00 P       100
5 Al    2000-01-03 17:00:00 F       400
6 Al    2000-01-03 17:00:00 P       900
7 Al    2000-01-07 20:00:00 F       500
8 Al    2000-01-07 20:00:00 P       999
```